# How to run a custom entry-point file on Rust Docker

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

I am using [the Rust official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust) for a web application. Since `Dockerfile` on the [official doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust#:%7E:text=Start%20a%20Rust%20instance%20running%20your%20app) ends with `CMD ["myapp"]`, I wonder how to specify an entry-point file whose file name is not `main.rs` using this docker image.

Specifically, the folder structure of my application is as follows, and I would like to run `src/main1.rs` using `Dockerfile1` and `src/main2.rs` using `Dockerfile2`.

```
├─Cargo.toml
├─Cargo.lock
├─Dockerfile1
├─Dockerfile2
└─src/
  ├─main1.rs
  └─main2.rs
```

As far as I know, `Cargo.toml` should be like this:

```
[package]
name = ...
version = ...
authors = ...

[[bin]]
name = "main1"
path = "src/main1.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "main2"
path = "src/main2.rs"
```

Comment: `cargo install --bins --path .` will install all binaries defined in the project.

Comment: @IvanC so will `cargo install --path .` since `--bins` is the default unless you specified `--bin something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you gave your binaries a name, namely `main1` and `main2` so you can make them the containers command with
`CMD ["main1"]`
or
`CMD ["main2"]`
respectively

While you're at it you might avoid the other binaries in the containers where they're not used replacing `RUN cargo install --path .` with `RUN cargo install --bin mainN --path .` in the docker files.

---

And a side note, `cargo` automatically creates binary crates for Rust files in `src/bin` so instead of adding `[[bin]]` tables for every binary you might to just want to change your layout to

```
├─Cargo.toml
├─Cargo.lock
├─Dockerfile1
├─Dockerfile2
└─src/
  └─bin/
    ├─main1.rs
    └─main2.rs
```

with a `Cargo.toml` of just

```ini
[package]
name = ...
version = ...
authors = ...
```

to produce the same result.